# Sketch Upload to LinkIt ONE Timeout

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-ide, wifi, gps

I've just bought a new LinkIt ONE IoT prototyping board, and I'm having trouble getting started with it.

I'm working on a mac. I've installed the LinkIt ONE SDK onto my Arduino IDE as specified in the instructions here: http://labs.mediatek.com/fileMedia/download/5fed7907-b2ba-4000-bcb2-016a332a49fd

When I go to upload my first sketch to my board, the sketch compiles and goes through uploading, but before it uploads, it stops uploading and the Arduino IDE perpetually tells me "Uploading...". When I look at the console below, it's telling me this:

```
[txd] AT


[txd] AT

[medrv]: Time out call back

[error] time out
[medrv]: Kill timer, event is AT_TIMEOUT
```

I've read some forums about an issue similar to this on the MediaTek website, but they don't help with the issue on the Mac. The ability to use LinkIt ONE on a Mac is new only this month, so I believe if we come up with a fix for this issue, it will help lots of people in the future who have this similar problem.

Comment: I should add that I'm unable to select the specified USB port when I click Tools > Port > (required port specified by MediaTek)

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I do not have access to one of these devices to test this on.*

Section 3.4.1 of [LinkIt's developer's guide](http://labs.mediatek.com/fileMedia/download/5fed7907-b2ba-4000-bcb2-016a332a49fd) (which you linked to) seems to indicate that it is necessary to install COM port drivers on OS X before you can communicate with the board. The `[txd]` report is communication from your computer to the board, so it seems like you are never establishing a connection. The suggestions in the developer's guide are as follows:

> If you are using a LinkIt ONE development board on Mac OS X 10.10, then a USB driver is required to enable connectivity with and firmware updates on the LinkIt ONE development board. The OS X 10.10 built-in generic CDC ACM USB driver is not compatible with three ports available on the LinkIt ONE development board. The steps to install a custom driver to enable the BROM port for Firmware Updater are as follows:
>
> 1. Extract the content of the zip file available in LinkIt ONE SDK software’s **Driver** folder (see 2.3.2, “Installing LinkIt ONE SDK”) named `MacOS_USB_COM_Driver_BM_xxx.xx.x.zip`.
> 2. Run the installation package (`BMCDCACM_Driver_v115.05.0.mpkg`) and click **Next** to install it.
> 3. Wait until driver installation has finished, then restart your Mac.
>
> BROM USB driver installation is now complete and you have access to the MTK USB Serial ports.